# Apps using AndroidX don't scale Text

Tags: android, textview, androidx, android-7.0-nougat

Text related fields do not scale if user change the font size from system settings. If the user set the text to the smallest size on the app keeps the same size, if it sets to be largest text size on the app keeps the same size.

Things to consider is I'm using AndroidX and its fresh project and so far this problem only happened on android 7, not seen on android 6,8,9 or 10.
This problem started to happen after upgrade my project to use AndroidX.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a fresh android project using android studio 3.5.3
2. Run the project using an android device, with android 7. At this point the system font size is regular.
3. Go to system settings and change the font size under the screen setting or under accessibility. The change the text size to the minimum or the largest size, as you prefer.
4. Restart the app or return the app.
5. You can see the hello world text isn't changed.
6. Ive tested devices running android 10, 9, 8, 7 and 6. But this seems to happen on android 7.

**Related Code**

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.marissa.and.alex.demotext"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

app/src/main/res/layout/content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see here this project was created just to test this scaling issue.

Comment: same issue seen in our production app....

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144151376 - not much hope though, never have I ever seen them reopen an issue.

Comment: Good news after all: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140607881 says it's fixed in appcompat-1.2.0-alpha02, but sadly, appcompat-1.2.0 is still in alpha. Still, links to workarounds are available there.